# what do these permissions mean?

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, chmod

I did `chmod` on some files in Mac 10.7.3 and I accidentally entered the code `7744` instead of `744`.

The resulting permissions were:

```
-rwsr-Sr-T
```

After seeing this I reran `chmod` and fixed the permissions to:

```
-rwxr--r--
```

I understand that I put a bad permissions code in, but I was curious what those permissions mean.

Any ideas?

Update

the command ran was:

`sudo chmod 7744 ./*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra 7 set the [`setuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) ("set user ID"), `setgid` ("set group ID"), and sticky bits in the permissions.

The "s" in the user permissions means it has execute and set ID permissions, the "S" in group means it has set ID but not execute, and the "T" in the other perms means it has the sticky bit but not execute (lowercase "t" would mean both execute and sticky).

See `man chmod` for details on the meaning of the extra digit, and `man ls` for details of how `ls` shows the results.